# Unhandled exception in InstallShield 2012 Uninstall

Tags: c#, installshield

I have a project that was build from InstallShield 2012 pro edition and it is an InstallScript project.  So when I have to do a patch I have no choice but to create a "Differential Release".  Here are what I did.

```
1. I set the product version to 1.6.2 from 1.6.1
2. I kept the Product GUID remains the same.
3. I generated the setup.exe and cab file and confirmed my install ran sucessfully.
4. I verified the fix is now in my application.
```

However when I tried to uninstall, I get the "Unhandled Exception" in the screenshot below.  I do not see any log in the Window Event viewer.

I verfied the Registry value uninstall path points to the proper path at C:\Program Files\InstallShield Installation Information{76B9582C-05B4-4FFB-9228-B61FD76A7E48}

I get the screenshot below regardless if I run the uninstall from the add/remove software or I run the Setup.exe manually from the above path.  My question is do you know anything about this type or error or if I somehow can output the /verbose logging to a file to at least know what type of error I am looking at.

Please remember my project is InstallScript project and not Basic MSI project.  I already visit the command [**page**](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield15helplib/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm) for setup.exe but I can't find anything that let me output any error to a file.

Anyone have any suggestion how I can find out more about the error I am seeing?

[image]

Comment: An appropriate google query is "installshield uninstall log location".  Lots of hits, the top one is the site where you are most likely to get an answer to these kind of questions.

Comment: thank you for your input, but I hope you gave me more credit for the leg works I've done before asking the question here.  I did that and clicked on every links on the first 3 pages and still got no satisfied result.  Most of the answers found is for Basic MSI or InstallScript MSI project.  Always easy to tell someone to google up.

Comment: The first question I'd have is whether the non-differential build suffers from the same problem, or whether the problem is specific to the differential build. (In my experience the complexities associated with "patches" and "differential builds" yield a poor ROI in all but the simplest cases.)